# matlab quadrature

Tags: matlab, integral

I'm trying to use MATLAB [dblquad](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dblquad.html) for such an equation:

```
f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}(exp(-int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx))dy
```

[image: f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}(exp(-int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx))dy]

But it does not work. Is there any suitable MATLAB function for these type of double integrations?

Thanks a lot,
mg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested integral rather than a double integral so `dblquad` will not work. How about

```
q = quad(@(y)arrayfun(@(w)exp(-quad(f,0,w)),y),0,1)
```